# Is it possible to scale a JApplet to more resolutions

Tags: java, applet, scaling

I have a Java Applet, which contains a table, some buttons and comboboxes. 
Because of the design I needed to make the GUI in Netbeans with a custom layout and for fixed size (1600x900). Because of the strange behaviour, I also needed to disable for each component the resizeable property.
The full code is below.

I know, that modifying the "false" in the grouplayout to "true" will make the applet scalable, but that way the design will get really messed up.

So is there a way to rescale the whole applet as one? Not necessarily to all resolutions, but to two or three lower resolutions (without redesign it from scratch).
I searched a lot about this topic, and I couldn't find anything good for my case.

Anticipated thanks!

**Later edit**

The java file for the GUI:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/msywcqmn74nftq1/GUI_demo.java
```

I tried to get rid of all what is not necessary for graphics, but even so, it is around 700 lines and was to large to post here...

and the image in the smallest resolution (~1200x700) 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/120500344@N07/13638500165/ 
(I do not have enough reputation to post images...)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for your reply, I edited my post and added the code and the image, hope that it will be helpful

Comment: Uncompilable code snippets are not an MCVE..  Please, follow the link, read about it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry, now I did a cleaning of the code, and posted a minimalist example of the GUI, which can be compiled. Even so it is a little bit large, but all those parts are necessary for graphics...